# Unable to connect to database in Openshift

Tags: php, postgresql, openshift

I'm running a scaled TinyTinyRSS cartridge, which includes PHP 5.3, a Web Load Balancer, Cron 1.4, and PostgreSQL 9.2.

When I go to the page, I am getting the error:

> Unable to connect to database (as [username] to 5401f66a4382ec91770000e2-rmorabia.rhcloud.com, database rss):Unable to connect to database (as [username] to 5401f66a4382ec91770000e2-rmorabia.rhcloud.com, database rss):

By the way, the link to my app is [here](http://rss-rmorabia.rhcloud.com).

I'm not sure what the problem is. It worked at the beginning, and it hasn't been for the past few days. If you could tell me what information would be helpful to put here, that'd be great.

Possibly of interest, the PHP 5.3 cartridge has a "Idle" status. I was also unable to restart the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a

```
rhc app-force-stop {appname}
```

and then

```
rhc restart -a {appname}
```

Comment: It turns out that I'm using 100% of my disk space. Thanks.

Comment: For people who come across this same question the way to check your disk quota would be:

rhc app-show {app name} --gears quota